# Execute script on ajax requested page before page loads

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have a AJAX based website navigation. One is **index.html** other is **profile.html**.
The content of both pages is like this:

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="script1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
<nav class="main-nav">.....{{nav-content}}.....</nav>
<div class"content">
---{{main-content}}-----
</div>
</body>
```

On both the pages I have all the scripts linked that may be needed anywhere on website.
On **profile.php** I have a tabs widget that is triggred using **$("div#mySliderTabs").sliderTabs();**.

When I load profile.php's `<div class=".content"></div>` content using **.load()** and I have to manually execute **$("div#mySliderTabs").sliderTabs();** as *.load() callack* again to make sliderTabs working.

Is there any way to make sliderTabs work without triggering the script again and load the resulting html `<div class=".content"></div>` content's only into current page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. SliderTabs needs a DOM element as far as i know. That means it needs to be present to be instantiated.
There are other options though

1. you could load the new content, save it in a jQuery collection and execute `sliderTabs()` without it being in the DOM. Then you could add it whenever you want. `sliderTabs()` still needs to be executed after your AJAX call though.
2. sliderTabs could use bubbling events to make - for example - click events work. Like this:

__

```
$('document').on('click', '#sliderButton', function() {
    // do the sliding
});
```

The buttons will have their event listeners even when they're loaded with AJAX afterwards.